# mongodb - abuse of system.users collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple mongodb app. Users create accounts when they login.

When a user creates their account I have to store the extra data somewhere.

Currently I'm extending the **system.users** collection in mongodb and adding a bunch of fields to it. However it is a 'system' collection so I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

Is this 'bad practice'? Should I instead create a user_details collection and map it to the system.users table with the use of the '_id' foreign key style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a bad idea. `system.users` collection is supposed to store authentication details of users that are allowed to access your database. DB users and app users are two very different entities!

My suggestion: stop messing with system collections. Or else it will surely backfire in the future.

Comment: certain frameworks merge the concept of DB users and App users. But I will take your advice and stop using system.users